# Mist 0.9 Using Private Node on Local g0-Ethereum Wallet - How to start without an Internet connection

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

Mist 0.9 Using Private Node on Local Ethereum Wallet - 
How to start without an Internet connection

Windows 10 - go-Ethereum Wallet starts up and mines 
Mist 0.9 will not start without an internet connection ie points to  URL -
 https://wallet.ethereum.org/

So I can work offline on the train for Solidity Dev